# Jhipster webpack production ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts ,Module not found:Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, angular5, jhipster, angular-fullstack

When did I run **yarn run webpack:prod** , 
it showed -> **ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/myProject/src/main/webapp/app'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 2:0-62**

I am using : 
Jhipster version : 4.13.3
Angular : 5.1.0
Jdk-1.8
os - ubuntu 18.04

Here I have shared my package.json file as well.

**package.json**

`{
      "name": "myProject",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "description": "Description for bookingspider",
      "private": true,
      "license": "UNLICENSED",
      "cacheDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "5.1.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "ng-jhipster": "0.3.6",
        "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
        "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
        "primeng": "^5.0.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "5.5.5",
        "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
        "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
        "tether": "1.4.0",
        "webstomp-client": "1.0.6",
        "zone.js": "0.8.16"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.5",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
        "@types/node": "8.0.18",
        "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
        "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
        "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "1.1.5",
        "generator-jhipster": "4.13.3",
        "html-loader": "0.5.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
        "karma": "1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
        "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
        "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
        "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.11",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.9",
        "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
        "rimraf": "2.6.1",
        "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
        "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
        "tslint": "5.5.0",
        "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
        "typescript": "2.5.3",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.5",
        "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
        "webpack": "3.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
        "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-beta.1",
        "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
        "xml2js": "0.4.17"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.9.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
        "lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
        "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
        "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
        "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
        "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
        "serve": "yarn run start",
        "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
        "test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
        "test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
        "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
        "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
        "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
        "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
        "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
        "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
        "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
        "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
        "postinstall": "node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
      }
    }`

**app.main.ts :**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ProdConfig } from './blocks/config/prod.config';
import { MyProjectAppModule } from './app.module';

ProdConfig();

if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyProjectAppModule)
.then((success) => console.log(`Application started`))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I tried every possible solution I could find on google and nothing worked.

Can anyone please help me for this issue? TIA

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `@angular/*` dependencies to 5.1.1 to get real error as suggested in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20292 ? Also consider using exact versions in your package.json and not `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 5.1.0 doesn't show me the actual error. I have been resolved the issue by updated my angular 5.1.0 to **5.1.1**. After that build the project for production it showed me the actual error, that I didn't import a component in my **app.module.ts** file.